Why is the translation of estanque as millpond justified?
Gabriela Mistral's poem El amor que calla contains the following lines (from the third stanza, emphasis mine):

Estoy lo mismo que estanque colmado
y te parezco un surtidor inerte.

Google Translate gives the following translation (emphasis mine):

I am like a full pond
and I seem to you like an inert fountain.

Ursula K. Le Guin translates these lines as follows:

A millpond full to overflowing,
I seem to you a spring gone dry.

(Selected Poems of Gabriela Mistral, translated by Ursula K. Le Guin. University of New Mexico Press, 2003, page 13.)
According to Wiktionary, estanque has the following meanings:

pool, pond (artificial, small inland body of water)
small reservoir, tank
kiosk; stand

The Spanish translation of millpond is balsa de molino or estanque de molino. Colmado simply means "full", without a connection to mills.
Why is the translation of "estanque" as "millpond" justified? I am particularly interested in a poetic justification, not arguments that simply say, "Oh, estanque is broad enough to include that meaning anyway."

I don't know any Spanish, but in Wiktionary, estanque is defined as "artificial, small inland body of water". English doesn't have a word for an artificial pond, so possibly LeGuin used millpond to emphasize that it was artificial. I don't know why its being artificial would be important to the poem.

Also, it is, like the original term, two syllables.

@Mary But isn't estanque 3 syllables?

@ClaraDíazSanchez  The search engine turned up two syllables, which would not have been my guess.  At any rate, two is better than one for a three syllable substitute.

@ClaraDíazSanchez It's not a syllable-for-syllable match; that's irrelevant to Le Guin's translation method, as can be seen from the other pairs of corresponding words here. It's a beat-for-beat (stress) match. In other words, it fits the English rhythm better, and the English rhythm is based only loosely on the Spanish rhythm, without attempting to match the Spanish rhythm word by word. The two words' lengths are important relative to their respective lines, not to each other's lengths.

@LukeSawczak I was specifically answering Mary's point, not making any referrence to Le Guin's translation. Someone trying to pronounce "estanque" as a French word may think it has two syllables. But in fact it has three.

@ClaraDíazSanchez Gotcha. I should've done @Mary!

Is there any link between estanque and the way the word tank is used in English spoken in India to refer to an artificial pond?

@LeeC. It seems that tankh is an original Indic language root that might actually have given English its tank, though that entry notes that some dictionaries claim this is coincidence and we got it from the Portuguese estancar "to hold back a current of water".

I believe there are two threads which must be unpicked here: what was the imagery that Mistral was trying to invoke, and by using the word “millpond”, does Le Guin’s translation successfully evoke the same image in the translated version.
An “estanque” is indeed a small body of water, which has often been created artificially. In the central park in Madrid (El Retiro), for example, there is an artificial boating lake which is simply called “el estanque”. I am from Andalucia, however, and there the most common use of estanque1 is to refer to the little reservoirs of water in the mountains created by damming small valleys. These fill up with water over the winter and provide water for farming (and people) during the rest of the year. Mistral grew up  in the Elqui Valley in Chile
an agricultural area which contains many reservoirs to provide water throughout the year, of which the Puclaro reservoir is the largest. I cannot be certain, but I think it is plausible that this is the sense of estanque that Mistral had in mind, a body of water that has been dammed up.
If we now look at the poem we see that Mistral is describing her love as rendering her mute. In the first verse she tells that if she hated the person she is addressing, she would shout out her words. Because she loves this person, however, her words are unsure. In the second verse she tells that she cannot shout out about her love, her words instead “falter before they reach her throat” (esfallecido, antes de la garganta).
This image of suppression continues in the final verse. Mistral writes “Estoy lo mismo que estanque colmado /
y te parezco un surtidor inerte”. Interpreting the estanque as a dammed valley, I could slightly exaggerate these lines to write  “I am like a mighty hydroelectric project, from which only a tiny dribble of water emerges”, describing how the writer is full of emotion but is unable to express it. From Collins dictionary, a millpond is defined as:

a pool formed by damming a stream to provide water to turn a
millwheel

any expanse of calm water


While the word is often used in the second sense as a metaphor for stillness, I believe that Le Guin is using it in the first sense, as a body of water held back by a dam. This more or less matches the usage of estanque as I have described above, except that the dammed water in an estanque is usually just used as a store, rather than to power a mill. The word “millpond” may simply be Le Guin's solution to finding a simple, brief, and non-technical term that can be used to evoke this sense of a body of water artificially restrained by a dam.
 1. Apart from its informal meaning of a liquor store. 

"reservoir" is probably the most specific English word to define a body of water artificially restrained by a dam. But, firstly, it wouldn't give such a good metre as "millpond" (as Mary noted in comments), and secondly, the word "reservoir" feels a bit more technical whereas "millpond" may fit better with the timeless subject of the poem.

Yes, it sounds more technical, and it also has too many syllables to nicely fit in the line.

@ClaraDíazSanchez Also, millpond may have been a better translation than reservoir for Ursula Le Guin because Californians (Ursula Le Guin grew up in California) think of reservoirs as being very large, because you need huge reservoirs when it only rains six months out of the year.

That sort of large reservoir would be "un embalse".

I am not a native speaker, but I do speak Spanish and to me, estanque brings to mind estancado, stagnant (which has negative connotations, unlike still). Assuming it isn't just me, if estanque also carries a connotation of estancado to native speakers, that might also explain the choice of millpond as that tends to be a relatively still body of water.

@terdon "if estanque also carries a connotation of estancado to native speakers" → It does not, as far as I can tell. If you asked me for the word to name a body of agua estancada, and you specified that you wanted it to carry the same negative connotation of the water being stagnant, pantano, balsa or even ciénaga would come to mind before estanque, which (to me at least) is an artificially contained body of water, yes, but not necessarily stagnant (as in, the water has some natural or artificial flow that allows it to stay clean).

@terdon estanque and estancado have the same root, but it just means non-flowing. There is no negative connotation (at least to me).

Interesting. Thanks @walen, Clara. That's the kind of thing non natives are bound to confuse. Since I learned estancado before estanque, I always linked them in my mind and gave both the same mild negative connotation. Thanks for the clkarification!

In addition to the good ideas mentioned about possible semantic overlap, i.e. that an estanque is a particular type of pond, I believe that rhythm has played more than a small part in Le Guin's choice.
Mistral's poem has roughly four strong beats per line:

Estoy lo mismo que estanque colmado
y te parezco un surtidor inerte.
¡Todo por mi callar atribulado
que es más atroz que el entrar en la muerte!

Le Guin's translation attempts to capture this rhythm by using iambic tetrameter, into which she has worked "millpond" very fluidly:

A millpond full to overflowing,
I seem to you a spring gone dry.

Generally speaking, multisyllabic words with the correct stresses feel more fluid than strings of monosyllabic words, hence any solution with "pond" is likely to be at least a little less pleasing. (For example, suppose she had tried something with "a full pond" — you would read that as a spondee rather than an iamb.)

"A pond that's full to overflowing" would have had the same metre, FWIW. (This doesn't contradict the point in your last paragraph, just maybe a better example for the parenthetical.)

@Randal'Thor Good point. That said, the dangling modifier is weakened a little bit by the relative clause (syntactically they're both dangling noun phrases, but somehow adding "that's" makes me less willing to read the implied copula with "I"!).

Where does the beat in "sur"(tidor) come from?

@walen I was somewhat unsure whether to stress te or sur, but based on the audio and parallelism with the first couple of unstressed syllables in the alternating 4th line, I decided on sur. Why, do you think te is stronger?

Both sur and te are unstressed; surtidor only has a stress on the last syllable: [suɾ.t̪iˈð̞oɾ]. There are no multi-stress words in Spanish (with the debatable exception of -mente adverbs and composed words). Reading surtidor with a stressed sur would sound totally weird. Hence my asking where it came from, maybe you had heard recorded audio of Mistral reading it like that on purpose or something.

Calm as a millpond is an old simile for a stretch of calm water, including the sea.
I see that colmado means full, not calm, but in view of the simile in the next line, perhaps Le Guin chose millpond because of the association of ideas with still water?

Agree that the literary context of 'millpond' as a measure of stillness is an important part of the translation, aside from its literal meaning.
